# нужно считать данные из файла и вывести их на экран

Tags: c++

в файле первое число описывает кол-во чисел,написанная программа не работает.
программа компилируется,но результата нет

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    int N;
    inp>>N;
    int mass[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        inp >> mass[i];
        cout << mass[i];
    }
    inp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: А файл у вас точно есть? Покажите файл (первые 10 сток достаточно, миллион строк не нужно).

Comment: Недостает проверки, что файл нормально открылся.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего что проблема в том, что рабочая директория программы отличается от той, в которой находится входной файл

Answer (score 0):

Сложно дать внятный ответ, ориентируясь на немногочисленные данные из вопроса (ваш вариант, к слову, у меня работает).

В общем, вот, попробуйте:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inp;
    inp.open("input.txt", ios::in);
    int N, t;
    inp >> N;
    if(inp.is_open())
    {
        for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        {
            inp >> t;
            cout << t << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    { cout << "error: couldn't open file" << '\n'; }
    inp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

input.txt:

10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10